# iPad: RAM and virtue memory question of allocation...

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can / how... I define 2 matrices to be in virtue memory so I can use the RAM to perform matrix multiplication?

Is video RAM separate from main memory?  Or can I use that to do matrix multiplication... the advantage may be speed, if so?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All allocated memory will be in "virtual memory".  If you malloc() a hunk of memory, that is "virtual" memory.

But it sounds like you needs something faster?  Do you have performance analysis that indicates a problem?

In any case, you'll likely want to look into OpenCL, if you really need that extra speed.

Comment: are there limitation to how large a block I can have in virtue memory, ie... can I use 8 gigs for a matrix ?  thx

Comment: It is "virtual memory" not "virtue memory".  You are working with a 32 bit address space so, no, not 8 GB.  Nor 4. Given that the device likely has less than 8 GB of storage free, even a crafty paging algorithm is going to be a performance lose. Not too mention that an iOS device's bus speed is pretty darned slow.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Matrix multiplication with very large matrices.  I would like to get some sense of limitation.  Can I do matrix mult with 1,000,000 elements (double) in each matrix?  I have gone much larger on a PC, but doubt I can do anything close to that on the iPad.  maybe (char) might work...1 byte vs 8 bytes (char) vs (double)... if I remember correctly.

Comment: The problem isn't so much data in your case, but purely I/O and CPU power.  The iPad simply isn't a desktop computation engine.  Data size will certainly be an issue, but if you can get the data onto the device somehow, you can probably use mapped data (and careful unmapping) to be able to effectively page through the data.   Down this path many challenges lie.  Fortunately, they are pretty interesting.